# Running optimize_for_inference on InceptionV1 results in different output tensors?

Tags: tensorflow

I have a C++ application which is able to run Tensorflow models, both Inception V1 and V3.

I am also able to successfully run both optimize_for_inference and quantize_graph on my InceptionV3 graph / protocol buffer

However, running optimize_for_inference on InceptionV1 (inception5h.zip from Tensorflow, which I believe is also referred to as GoogleNet?), results in a much much smaller graph size (17 MB versus 54 MB), but it also is no longer functional with my application.

Running the Optimized graph results in errors stating the tensor named 'output' is no longer available.

I understand optimize_for_inference makes changes to the structure of the graph removing unnecessary nodes. However, I specify my outputs as such:

```
$ bazel-bin/tensorflow/python/tools/optimize_for_inference --input=/Users/vade/Documents/Repositories/Synopsis/Synopsis/Synopsis/TensorFlowAnalyzer/models/inception5h/tensorflow_inceptionV2_graph.pb --output=/Users/vade/Documents/Repositories/Synopsis/Synopsis/Synopsis/TensorFlowAnalyzer/models/inception5h/tensorflow_inceptionV2_graph_optimized.pb --input_names=input --output_names=output,softmax0
```

Which in my mind would keep my output tensors named the same.

Running the resulting graph (tensorflow_inceptionV2_graph_optimized.pb) through my C++ app results in this error:

```
 Running model failed: Not found: FetchOutputs node output: not found
```

How can I resolve this issue, or deduce the new output tensor name?

Thank you.